# Resetting PasswordChar for tComboBox fails

Tags: delphi

My user is entering a password into a combo box, so I want to show `*` in place of what the user types.
No problem so far. The routine shown below works perfectly. 
But, I also want to give the user the choice of showing the password.
When I call the routine below with SetPasswordChar=false, it sends EM_SETTPASSWORDCHAR with parameter zero. I expect the combo box to show the text entered by the user.  But it still shows `*`.
Any idea what I'm missing?

```
//==============================================================================
// SetComboBoxPasswordChar
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set the Password Char for a tComboBox.
//
// This is done using by sending an EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR message to the edit box
// sub-control of the combo box.
//
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761653(v=vs.85).aspx
//
// wParam - The character to be displayed in place of the characters typed by
// the user. If this parameter is zero, the control removes the current password
// character and displays the characters typed by the user.
//==============================================================================

procedure SetComboBoxPasswordChar
            ( const nComboBox        : tComboBox;
              const nSetPasswordChar : boolean    );
var
  C : integer;
  H : tHandle;
begin

  // Get handle of the combo box

  H := nComboBox . Handle;

  // Get handle of the edit-box portion of the combo box

  H := GetWindow ( H, GW_CHILD );

  // If nSetPasswordChar is true,
  // set password char to asterisk
  // Otherwise, clear the password char

  if nSetPasswordChar then
    C := ord('*')
  else
    C := 0;

  SendMessage ( H, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, C, 0 );
end;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a ComboBox to do this? A Combobox is designed to display a list of items the user can choose from (and optionally use the edit control to add additional items). Using a standard TEdit control would not only make more sense from a GUI standpoint, but would also make things simple: just change the `PasswordChar` property. It seems to me you're working too hard to do something that seems wrong in the first place from a UI standpoint.

Comment: That's a good point Ken.  The application allows the user to select sql server, database, user name and password.  The first three of these will have a drop-down history so the user doesn't have to re-type common values.  I made the password edit the same just so they'd all look the same, but, you're right, it doesn't make sense. ... Still an interesting question why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect (and just confirmed with a quick test app in XE2) it's because you're just assuming that the edit control's  `HWND` is what gets returned by `GetWindow(H, GW_CHILD);`, and I don't think that's a safe assumption. :-) The `COMBOBOX` control is actually composed of three `HWND` values: one for the entire control, one for the edit portion, and one for the drop-down list.

The more proper way to get the handle you want is to use [GetComboBoxInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use the `hwndItem` member of the [COMBOBOXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure:

```
var
  CBI: TComboBoxInfo;
begin
  // ..... Other code
  CBI.cbSize := SizeOf(CBI);
  H := nComboBox.Handle;
  if GetComboBoxInfo(H, CBI) then
    SendMessage(cbi.hwndItem, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, C, 0);
end;
```

For a quick, easy illustration that it works, drop a `TComboBox` on a new blank form, add an event handler for the `ComboBox1.OnDblClick` event handler, and add the following code to your form:

```
const
  PasswordChars: array[Boolean] of Integer = (0, Ord('*'));
var
  Ch: Integer = 0;
  UsePWdChar: Boolean = False;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ch: Integer;
  CBI: TComboBoxInfo;
begin
  CBI.cbSize := SizeOf(CBI);
  UsePwdChar := not UsePwdChar;
  Ch := PasswordChars[UsePwdChar];
  if GetComboBoxInfo(ComboBox1.Handle, CBI) then
    SendMessage(cbi.hwndItem, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Ch, 0)
end;
```

This uses the default `ComboBox1` value in the edit control of the `ComboBox`, and toggles it back and forth between a password char of `*` and having none every time you double-click the combobox.

Comment: `TComboBox` has a public `EditHandle` property that contains the `HWND` of the edit field when the `Style` property is set to either `csDropDown` or `csSimple`.

Comment: @Remy, that's good to know. I don't use it that way, so I'd never noticed. The question still was how to use the `EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR` message, though. I personally wouldn't use a ComboBox for password entry regardless of what mode - see my comment above to the question. Also, it's not present in the standard `TComboBox` in D2007's version of the VCL - is this something added with the switch to Unicode and update to later ComCtl versions?

Comment: Actually, it's not public in `TComboBox` or `TCustomComboBox` in XE2, either. You have to go all the way up to `TCustomCombo`, and it's a `protected` property there that's not exposed in either descendant. You'd have to use the `THackCombo=class(TCustomCombo)` and typecast to get to it, which isn't any more work than declaring the record,  filling it, and using the message.

Comment: A hack class is evaluated at compile-time, so you can leverage the work that `TCustomCombo` already does at run-time to obtain the `HWND` whether you use it or not. Its more work to duplicate that run-time effort to obtain the same `HWND` manually. Its a matter of personal choice which way you want to do it. Personally, I don't like duplicating work.

Comment: @Remy: Personally, I don't either. :-) But personally, as I've said twice before, I wouldn't use a `ComboBox` for a password entry control, so I would never need to use either technique.

Comment: True enough, I wouldn't use a ComboBox for password entry, either.